# Compendium of elliptic curves?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, elliptic-curves

does anyone know where I can find a collection of elliptic curves and their integral solutions?

EDIT: Removed additional useless info.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of "collection" are you looking for? This is extremely vague.

Comment: Were you trying to ask for an elliptic curve which has the same shape as the one you described?

Comment: Or you mean a collection of elliptic curves with some *integer* solutions of it?

Comment: Any equation of the form $y^2 = x^3 + ax+b$ with $4a^3 + 27b^2 \neq 0$ (i.e. non-zero discriminant) is called an elliptic curve. That's why I'm asking for more precision.

Comment: All solutions of what type? Integer? Rational?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [L-functions and modular forms database](http://www.lmfdb.org) (LMFDB) contains a [large database of elliptic curves](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/) organised by a variety of invariants. These pages include data on integral points e.g. [this curve](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/61.a1) has a few, if you want a curve with lots of integral points I guess looking in the higher rank categories would be better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of an elliptic curve with its 8 integral points (16 if you count $\pm y$) given by $y^2 = x^3 + 17$ :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve

Go look under the section "integral points".

Hope that helps,